# Playing a decoded MP3 file

Tags: java, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode (base64) a mp3 file, save it to database, and then later retrieve it and decode it and play the file. I have put in the following code, but it doesn't seem to work. Any fixes I can do to make it work?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ReadAudioFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String file = "C:\\Users\\Mukkra01\\Downloads\\apple.mp3";
        InputStream byteInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64(inputStreamToByteArray(byteInputStream)));
        byte[] decodeFile = Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.encodeBase64(inputStreamToByteArray(byteInputStream)));
        play(decodeFile);
    }

    public static byte[] inputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void play(byte[] decodeFile) {
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeFile);
            //BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Mukkra01\\Downloads\\apple.mp3"));
            Player player = new Player(byteInputStream);
            player.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try encoding / decoding a text file.  If that works, your problem is in the MP3 playback.  If it doesn't work, then you know your problem is the deconversion doesn't match the conversion.